# How to provide custom input on "Do you want to continue" prompt in ansible?

Tags: server, ansible

While using Linux when we try to install something using the command line we get a prompt

```
"Do you want to continue"[Y/N]..
```

I want to automate it using an ansible-playbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of use case, the [module expect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html) could be use.

For example in your case a basic task looks like this :

```
- name : "Provide custom input"
  expect:
    command: 'launch.sh'
    responses:
      'Do you want to continue\"\[Y\/N\]\"': 'y'
```